# Receiving Python tokening error when reading file from HUE HDFS website

Tags: python, csv, parsing, unicode, tokenize

I am currently trying to pull a text file from a HDFS hue website. Having a lot of trouble pulling in the data in order to do nlp sentiment analysis on it. I've even tried converting it from a txt file to a csv file.

My code is below.

```
with client.read(hdfsPath + "/test data/negative.csv") as reader:
        short_neg = pd.read_csv(reader, header = None)

fileName = 'negative.csv'
pdfdoc = read_pdf(hdfsPath, fileName)
```

At first I was getting this error:

**UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x97 in position 56: invalid start byte**

So I changed the encoding to encoding = 'cp1252' and header = None

However, I keep receiving this message:

**ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 7 fields in line 2, saw 16**

The first 2 lines of the text document look like this where each row is supposed to be 1 review:

*simplistic , silly and tedious .*

*it's so laddish and juvenile , only teenage boys could possibly find it funny .*

Is there any sufficient remedy for this?

*Edit: here is the traceback pasted below*

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-234-2f319e7fdde5> in <module>()
      3     #column_names = [i for i in range(max(col_count))]
      4     #short_neg = pd.read_csv(reader, header = None, names = column_names, encoding= 'cp1252')
----> 5     short_neg = pd.read_csv(reader, header = None, encoding= 'cp1252', sep= " ")
      6 
      7 

~/anaconda/envs/anaconda50_hadoop/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    684     )
    685 
--> 686     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    687 
    688 

~/anaconda/envs/anaconda50_hadoop/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    456 
    457     try:
--> 458         data = parser.read(nrows)
    459     finally:
    460         parser.close()

~/anaconda/envs/anaconda50_hadoop/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1184     def read(self, nrows=None):
   1185         nrows = _validate_integer("nrows", nrows)
-> 1186         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
   1187 
   1188         # May alter columns / col_dict

~/anaconda/envs/anaconda50_hadoop/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   2143     def read(self, nrows=None):
   2144         try:
-> 2145             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
   2146         except StopIteration:
   2147             if self._first_chunk:

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 7 fields in line 2, saw 16
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: @lenz just added the code